enable BitLocker full disk encryption WITHOUT storing keys in the TPM windows 11
I am on Windows 11 and want to encrypt my Drive, i have a modern laptop with a TPM which is really easy to sniff via the solder points on the motherboard,
I want a regular Password encryption required every time I want to boot, without any keys ending up in the tpm
I looked online and people point to the BitLocker requires additional authentication group policy, and to enable the "allow BitLocker without compatible TPM", I am really  puzzled if this is really enough for Windows to not put any keys in the TPM

Those policies are for systems that need the unattended startup functionality of a TPM but without a TPM. Try the following:
manage-bde -on C:\ -password [password]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/manage-bde-on
